# Whenever i calculate square or squareroot with whatever input i get NAN?

Tags: java, android

Here is my code for these two functions:

```
else if(btn.getText().equals("sqr"))
    {
        BigDecimal LeftVal = new BigDecimal(currentInput);
        BigDecimal result = null;
        if(currentInputLen > 0 && currentInput !="0")
        {
            result = LeftVal.pow(2);        
        }
        inputText.setText(result+"");
    }
    else if(btn.getText().equals("sqrt"))
    {
        double LeftVal = Double.parseDouble(currentInput);
        double result = 0;
        if(currentInputLen > 0 && currentInput !="0")
        {
            result = Math.sqrt(LeftVal);        
        }
        inputText.setText(result+"");
    }
```

i can't figure out what is wrong.Below are declarations of currentInputLen and currentInput

```
String currentInput = inputText.getText().toString();
    int currentInputLen = currentInput.length();
```

Nothing appear to be wrong with them as i can calculate sin, cos, etc. just square and square root are causing problems.Here is the sin code that works perfectly well

```
else if(btn.getText().equals("sin"))
    {
        double LeftVal = Double.parseDouble(currentInput);
        double result = 0;
        LeftVal *=Math.PI;
        LeftVal/=180;
        if(currentInputLen > 0 && currentInput !="0")
        {
            result = Math.sin(LeftVal);         
        }
        inputText.setText(result+"");
    }
```

when i give input 90 it outputs 1.0

It works now with this code

```
else if(btn.getText().equals("+")||btn.getText().equals("-")||btn.getText().equals("/")||btn.getText().equals("x")||btn.getText().equals("pow")||btn.getText().equals("sqr"))
    {
        if (resetInput) {
            mInputStack.pop();
            mOperationStack.pop();
        } else {
            if (currentInput.charAt(0)=='-') {
                mInputStack.add("(" + currentInput + ")");
            } else {
                mInputStack.add(currentInput);
            }
            mOperationStack.add(currentInput);
        }

        mInputStack.add(text);
        mOperationStack.add(text);

        dumpInputStack();
        evalResult = evaluateResult(false);
        if (evalResult != null)
            inputText.setText(evalResult);

        resetInput = true;
    }
```

Then after few lines of code there are these lines:

```
private String evaluateResult(boolean requestedByUser) {
    if ((!requestedByUser && mOperationStack.size() != 4)
            || (requestedByUser && mOperationStack.size() != 3))
        return null;

    String left = mOperationStack.get(0);
    String operator = mOperationStack.get(1);
    String right = mOperationStack.get(2);
    String tmp = null;
    if (!requestedByUser)
        tmp = mOperationStack.get(3);

    BigDecimal leftVal = new BigDecimal(left);
    BigDecimal rightVal = new BigDecimal(right);
    BigDecimal result = null;

else if (operator.equals("sqr"))
    {
        result = leftVal.pow(2);
    }
```

The output is as shown in pic
[image: I do not want the square to appear there but just the result]

Comment: Are you sure that LeftVal is a positive?

Comment: What exactly is the symptom? Do show one of your working clauses, e.g. sin(). Your code `result+""` looks like it should be `""+result` or simply `result.toString()`. In Java, a string + another value automatically converts the second value to a string.

Comment: Yes i am sure leftValue is positive.

Comment: Consider adding logging of the arguments and program flow, or running under a Java debugger

Comment: @Reimeus has a good point but reversed: You need to use `currentInput.equals("0")` if you want to test for string equality rather than identity. A text field's string will not be identical to a literal string.

Comment: I have edited my question to show a working sin code. i used !currentInput.equals("0") but still NAN
@Jerry101 did you mean i should use just currentInput.equals("0") and not !currentInput.equals("0")

Comment: FYI Math has also the toRadians and toDegree methods

Comment: @Programmingcat I meant you should nearly always use `.equals()` to compare strings, not `==` or `!=`. In this case, `!currentInput.equals("0")` but why skip the computation and emit 0 for "0" input? It won't do the same for, say, " 00". Better to test the parsed number LeftVal. Anyway, do step through the code in the debugger.

Comment: The code is working now but i don't know why if i post it here would any one explain that to me?

Comment: @Programmingcat try it. What did you change? Both Android Studio and Eclipse maintain local version history in addition to any source code control you may be using.

Comment: I have edited my post now there is output of working code.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing Strings by reference `!=` when you do:

```
if(currentInputLen > 0 && currentInput !="0")
```

Use `equals()` to compare strings everywhere (as you correctly did in your `else if` conditions). So do:

```
if(currentInputLen > 0 && !currentInput.equals("0"))
```

instead.

Comment: I am still getting NaN